# Getting name as USER OBJECT

Tags: django, heroku

I am building an app in django and I have deployed this app on Heroku. My error is I have "name" as a foreign key in my model when I am accessing name on my app which is deployed on Heroku name is shown as "USER OBJECT".

I am able to access correct name while running on the local server.

I have tried many different ways but still not able to fix it.

Pictures for a better understanding of my error.

[image]

Comment: I guess its a Python version conflict. What's your local python version and heroku python version?

Comment: @AamirAdnan i am using Python 2.7 on my system(local) and heroku is using
python-3.6.1

Comment: Whether or not this the source of your problem, seems like a good idea to use Python 2 on the server if you're using Python 2 for dev: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `Upload.__unicode__` method. On Local you have `Python2.7` hence doing `unicode(self.name)` returns the appropriate representation of object. While on Heroku you have `Python3.6.1` which expects you to provide `__str__` hence you need to implement `__str__` as well for compatibility:

```
class Upload(models.Modal):
    # other fields

    def __unicode__(self):
        retrun unicode(self.name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__unicode__().encode('utf-8')
```

Or simply use [python_2_unicode_compatible](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.python_2_unicode_compatible) and implement only `__str__`:

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Upload(models.Modal):
    # other fields

    def __str__(self):
        retrun str(self.name)
```

Otherwise in template you can simply do `{{ i.name.username }}` to get the username.

Comment: No problem, I have added more simpler approach using `python_2_unicode_compatible` decorator check it out.

Comment: Even better, use the same version of Python between development and production.

Answer (score 0):

For Example

```
Class User(models.Model):
   @property
   def get_fullname(self):
       return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

in the template `{{i.name.get_fullname}}`